# How to tell Photos MacOS to go to the date of a given photo in the library?

Tags: macos, photos, shortcuts-app

I have a rather large number of photos stored in Photos in iCloud.  After having to rebuild my local library the connection from a given photo in a shared album back to the original in my library has been broken.  So be it.

I, however, found that I could identify the date of the photo and then manually navigate to that date in my library to find the original.  I was wondering if it was possible to create a shortcut - either in Photos itself or just in the Finder - that allows me to right-click a photo and go directly to the library on that date and time.

How should I do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding your scenario correctly, but want to mention, just in case, that there is an option "show image in library" in the right-click menu?

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann That is the connection that has been broken.  The menu entry does not show up anymore, sadly.